# how to retrieve facebook data from a page that is not mine

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am working on automatic language processing, I want to retrieve data from facebook and build my dataset, the problem is that each time I try to retrieve this data, I encounter this problem:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Page Public Metadata Access requires either app secret proof or an app token",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "Azl7f9Wz5PDpX9K-dDIJ3xm"
  }
}
```

I understand that the problem lies in the app token, but the concern is that I cannot get it and I don't know how to do it, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Public meta data access does not cover this, the feed of a page is not meta data. You will have to submit your app for the Page Public Content Access feature.

The Page Public Content Access feature allows read-only access to public data on Pages for which you lack the manage_pages login permission.

Documentation on this can be found [by clicking this link.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/features-reference#reference-PAGES_ACCESS)